# Using the letter e (not natural log) in long division in Latex

Tags: polynom

I'm trying to do a long division in Latex but using the letter e, not x.  My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polynom}

\polyset{%
  style=A,
  delims={\big(}{\big)},
  div=:
}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \polylongdiv{e^4 + e^3 + 0e^2 - e - 1}{e-1}
  \]
\end{document}
```

The output is not the same as using x, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with how `polynom` parses the equation for the symbol `e`.  According to the documentation, declare a macro for it.

So, for example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polynom}

\polyset{%
  style=A,
  delims={\big(}{\big)},
  div=:
}

\newcommand\e{\mathit{E}}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \polylongdiv{\e^4 + \e^3 + 0\e^2 - \e - 1}{\e-1}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have just worked it out.  Just needed to put a vars=e in the polyset command.